# systemd service does not run

Tags: java, dropwizard, systemd

I have the following systemd file enabled in:
    /etc/systemd/system/pirestservice.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Raspberry Pi REST Service
After=local-fs.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/local/piservice/startpiservice.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The shell script referenced above is as follows, and is made executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo java -jar /usr/local/piservice/pirestservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server rest_metadata/template.yml
```

If i run the shell script, this dropwizard service does start up.  If I reboot, or start the service from the commandline, the service shows running if I do:

```
ps -ef | grep pirest
```

I will see a PID number assigned to the process.......HOWEVER....the service is not really running.  What am I missing?  Do I only need the one .service file, or are there other configurations I am missing?  Should the .service file be located in another directory?

At the end of the day I just want my application to run as a daemon/background service.

FYI, I am running this on a Raspberry Pi3 with Ubuntu Mate 16 installed.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Do you have something like "Press any key to exit" i.e. that your service is blocked by waiting on user input?

Answer (score 0):

Is java on the path?
And can the service script find your Dropwizard config file correctly?

My configuration looks like this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/myservice/myservice.jar server /opt/myservice/application.yml
```

Note that I use absolute paths for the java binary, and for the Dropwizard configuration file. If you don't want to hardcode the path to your configuration file, try to add this in the service file:

```
WorkingDirectory=/opt/myservice
```